# How to use bold option of V6.3 nicematrix?

Tags: nicematrix

I'd like to use the `\RowStyle` command by `nicematrix`, but I am having a problem with the new 6.3 version.

I used to use `\RowStyle{\bfseries}`, but now it seems the option has changed...

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\colorlet{Gray}{Lavender!80!gray}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[hbtp]
        \centering
        \caption{$d$-values of the reflex maxima of PD1 and PD2}
        \label{tab:reflex-values}
        \sisetup{table-format = 2.3}
        %    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
            \begin{NiceTabular}{lS[table-auto-round]lS[table-auto-round]}[baseline=1.2]
                \CodeBefore
                \rowcolors{2}{Gray}{white}
                \Body
                \toprule
                \RowStyle{\bfseries}
                \Block[c]{1-2}{PD1} & & \Block[c]{1-2}{PD2} & \\
                \midrule
                $\varphi_1$ [\si{\degree}] & 8.8848 & $\varphi_1$ [\si{\degree}] & 7.7048 \\
                $\vartheta_1$ [\si{\degree}] & 4.4424 & $\vartheta_1$ [\si{\degree}] & 3.8524 \\
                $d_1$ [\si{\angstrom}] & 9.944887 & $d_1$ [\si{\angstrom}] &  11.465158 \\
                $\varphi_2$ [\si{\degree}] & 28.1826 & $\varphi_2$ [\si{\degree}] & 9.1102 \\
                $\vartheta_2$ [\si{\degree}] & 14.0913 & $\vartheta_2$ [\si{\degree}] & 4.5551 \\
                $d_2$ [\si{\angstrom}] & 3.163863 & $d_2$ [\si{\angstrom}] & 9.699301 \\
                $\varphi_3$ [\si{\degree}] & {--} & $\varphi_3$ [\si{\degree}] & 26.1225 \\
                $\vartheta_3$ [\si{\degree}] & {--} & $\vartheta_3$ [\si{\degree}] & 13.06125 \\
                $d_3$ [\si{\angstrom}] & {--} & $d_3$ [\si{\angstrom}] & 3.408518 \\
                \bottomrule
            \end{NiceTabular}
            %    }
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Does not work anymore. How do I use the new `bold` key? Can one change the `bold` key from `boldmath` to `symbf` from unicode-math?

**EDIT:**
This somehow works as an MWE, but the same code (just different packages) in my main document causes some errors.

`Package xcolor: Undefined color 'false'.`

Comment: You should provide a full MWE that you could compile, that is to say with the `\documentclass`, the `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`, etc.

Comment: It looks that  there is a conflict  of RowStyle  with `siunitx`.  Using the example on page #16 `The command \Rowstyle` and a MWE it works fine with version 6.3 but stops with many errors just by having `\usepackage{siunitx}`

Comment: @Simon Dispa: Could you post another question with a MWE showing that behaviour? Thanks.

Comment: @F. Pantigny I posted as an answer to keep the thread together. I will delete it later.

Comment: @SimonDispa hope you aware that `F. Pantigny` is the `author` and the `maintainer` of `nicematrix.sty`

Comment: @MadyYuvi Indeed. Why is this a problem?

Comment: @SimonDispa No issues, just let you know...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the latest version of `siunitx` (2021-11-03 v3.0.35) and load it **before** `nicematrix`

[image: a]

Thanks to `F. Pantigny`  the author and the maintainer of `nicematrix` for his fast answer regarding the version of `siunitx`

Comment: This is perfect....